# UWP XAML exception when showing a ToolTip based on a user control, but only on second try

Tags: .net, xaml, uwp

I am trying to show a tooltip based on a user control.  It works perfectly the first time the ToolTip is shown, but when requested a second time, UWP throws an unhandled XAML exception: "The parameter is incorrect. The value does not fall into the expected range", this appears to be from System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal.NodeKeyValueCollection. Here is the XAML for the user control:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="KOTHMain.MapToolTipControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:KOTHMain"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="200"
d:DesignWidth="200"
DataContext="{x:Bind mMapToolTipView}">

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock x:Name="lblHeader1" Text="{x:Bind mMapToolTipView.Header1}" Style="{StaticResource KOTHToolTipStyle}"/>
    <ListView x:Name="lstStats" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind mMapToolTipView.StatsRows}" SelectionMode="None" MinHeight="10" MaxHeight="400">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/> 
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:StatsRowView">
                <Grid x:Name="grdListViewItem" Width="Auto">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="lblText" Grid.Column="0" Text="{x:Bind Text}" d:Text="Header" Style="{StaticResource KOTHToolTipStyle}" MinWidth="60" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="lblItem1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{x:Bind Item1}" Style="{StaticResource KOTHToolTipStyle}" MinWidth="60" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="lblSlash" Grid.Column="2" Text="/" Style="{StaticResource KOTHToolTipStyle}"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="lblItem2" Grid.Column="3" Text="{x:Bind Item2}" Style="{StaticResource KOTHToolTipStyle}" MinWidth="60" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

As I noted this works perfectly the first time the ToolTip is shown but fails the second.  I have traced this to some issue related to the XAML for the ListView (i.e., if the ListView is removed the error does not happen) and so far, I cannot find any issue with the code that creates the list and the User Control (it works first time and is only called once.)

Any help or thoughts would be appreciated.

---UPDATE 1/31---

Per request, here is more info:

The tooltip is applied to a number of 'icons' on a canvas.  Icons are simple border controls wrapping a textblock with a symbol character.  The number of icons, their position and other properties, and their tooltip is generated dynamically in the page code-behind and applied to the canvas when the page is loaded.  Most icons get a simple text string for a tooltip.  These work fine every time.  A few of the icons get the user control, these fail on the **second** attempt to show the ToolTip (via mouse over).  In each case, the ToolTip.Content property is set, either to a simple string or the user control, and it is only set once, on page load.

The user control itself is created by passing an object (MapToolTipPack) to its constructor that contains one Header text string and a generic List of type StatsRowView, where StatsRowView holds the Text, Item1, and Item2 fields for each row.  The mMapToolTipView property holds the very small View Model for the User Control.  This view model, MapToolTipView, is created and set when the user control is constructed and contains only two readonly properties that expose the Header and List of MapToolTipPack (which is passed via the view models constructor. (I have verified that these poperties are never called with the tooltip is shown, only when set on page load).

- TTPack = ToolTipPack(String, List of StatsRowView)
- ToolTip.Content = MapToolTipControl(ToolTipPack), where
- -- mMapToolTipView = MapToolTipView(ToolTipPack), which exposes
- ---- mMapToolTipView.Header and mMapToolTipView.StatsRows where each row has
- ------ StatsRowView.Text, StatsRowView.Item1, StatsRowView.Item2

As I noted this all works quite fine when only a string is provided as the ToolTip Content, and it works fine with the user control **if I comment out all XML related to the ListView**. But it will only dispaly the ToolTip once if the listView is included.

The error is not generated in my code behind and I have been unable to trap it, it is an unhandled XAML error that crashes the program.

Again, thanks for any consideration and help.

-- EDIT 2/1/2022 --

Per request, here is minimal XAML and Source code in a nearly blank test app.  Note that I get the XAML error in exactly the same way, no error with strings only, no error with the UserControl if the ListView control is commeneted out, but error with the UserControl if ListView is enabled, but only the second time the tooltip is shown.

```
<Page
x:Class="Test1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid>
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtIcon" Text="*" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="36"/>
</Grid>

</Page>

<UserControl
x:Class="Test1.ToolTipControl"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Test1"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="200"
d:DesignWidth="200"
DataContext="{x:Bind ToolTipView}">

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock x:Name="lblHeader1" Text="{x:Bind ToolTipView.Header}"/>
    <ListView x:Name="lstStats" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ToolTipView.StatsRows}" SelectionMode="None" MinHeight="10" MaxHeight="400">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:StatsRowView">
                <Grid x:Name="grdListViewItem" Width="Auto">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="lblText" Grid.Column="0" Text="{x:Bind Text}" d:Text="Header" MinWidth="60" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="lblItem1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{x:Bind Item1}" MinWidth="60" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="lblSlash" Grid.Column="2" Text="/" />
                    <TextBlock x:Name="lblItem2" Grid.Column="3" Text="{x:Bind Item2}" MinWidth="60" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

</Grid>
</UserControl>

Public NotInheritable Class MainPage
Inherits Page

Private Sub MainPage_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded

    Dim header As String = "Header Text"

    Dim rows As New List(Of StatsRowView)
    Dim row As New StatsRowView("Text1", "Item 1-1", "Item 1-2")
    rows.Add(row)

    Dim pack As New ToolTipPack(header, rows)
    Dim tooltipcontrol As New ToolTipControl(pack)

    ToolTipService.SetToolTip(txtIcon, tooltipcontrol)

End Sub

End Class

Public NotInheritable Class ToolTipControl
Inherits UserControl

Private ToolTipView As ToolTipView

Friend Sub New(ToolTipPack As ToolTipPack)

    InitializeComponent()

    Me.ToolTipPack = ToolTipPack

End Sub

Public Shared ReadOnly ToolTipPackProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ToolTipPack", GetType(ToolTipPack), GetType(UserControl), Nothing)
Friend Property ToolTipPack As ToolTipPack
    Get
        Return CType(GetValue(ToolTipPackProperty), ToolTipPack)
    End Get
    Set(value As ToolTipPack)
        SetValue(ToolTipPackProperty, value)
        ToolTipView = New ToolTipView(value)
    End Set
End Property

End Class

Friend Class ToolTipView

Private ReadOnly Property ToolTipPack As ToolTipPack

Friend Sub New(MapToolTipPack As ToolTipPack)
    _ToolTipPack = MapToolTipPack
End Sub

Friend ReadOnly Property Header As String
    Get
        Return ToolTipPack.Header
    End Get
End Property
Friend ReadOnly Property StatsRows As List(Of StatsRowView)
    Get
        Return ToolTipPack.StatsRows
    End Get
End Property

End Class

Friend Class ToolTipPack

Friend ReadOnly Property Header As String
Friend ReadOnly Property StatsRows As List(Of StatsRowView)

Friend Sub New(Header As String, Rows As List(Of StatsRowView))

    _Header = Header
    _StatsRows = Rows

End Sub

End Class

Friend Class StatsRowView

Friend ReadOnly Property Text As String
Friend ReadOnly Property Item1 As String
Friend ReadOnly Property Item2 As String

Friend Sub New(Text As String, Item1 As String, Item2 As String)

    _Text = Text
    _Item1 = Item1
    _Item2 = Item2

End Sub

End Class
```

Again, thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you please share more details like how you used the usercontrol as a tooltip and what is the `mMapToolTipView` object?

Comment: See 1/31 Edit above.

Comment: I have to say that I can't reproduce your issue with just the XAML code. So it's hard to locate this issue. Would you like to share code snippets that could reproduce this issue in a blank app??

Comment: See 2/1 Edit above.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the code. I could reproduce this. I handled the unhandled exception in the App.cs, the error message is that **The parameter is incorrect.**. I'm not sure which is the root cause for this. My suggestion is that avoid using `listview` in the tooltip, like using `Grid` with rows. I'll continue to investigate this behavior.

Comment: Yes, that is the error I get in the same place. Since I know the maximum number of rows and it's not too large, I have done what you noted and used a grid, hiding unused rows.   Thanks for looking at it.

Comment: Got some information from the team. This issue is related to how UWP calls the Direct Manipulation manager. Please open an issue on https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues . So the team could continue digging this.

Comment: I have submitted a GitHub issue as requested.